# how do i close an app?

Tags: android, splash-screen

i have a splash screen that has some code that i only want called once so after showing the splash screen it goes to my main game, and i don't want it going back to the splash screen again until the game is launched again. but when i hit back on my main screen, it goes back to the splash screen. how do i make the game close when the back button is pressed from the main screen instead of going back to the splash screen?

here is what i have right now on my main game, but it still goes back to the splash...

```
   @Override  
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"back was pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();

            return true;
            }

            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `finish()` in the splash activity right after you do `startActivity()` :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are starting the Activity you can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) for a reference. I'm sure you can do the same somehow if it is your initial activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a call to `finish()` in your onResume method for the Splash activity. Jack's solution is probably best though.